# Will local variable assignment always be executed, even if variable is unused?

Tags: c#, variable-assignment, compiler-optimization

I have a static container class that holds a handle to some class `A`:

```
public static class Container
{
    private static A _a;        
    public static void Register(A a) { _a = a; }
    public static void Run() { _a.DoIt(); }
}
```

Registration of the container `A` instance is performed in the `A` constructor:

```
public class A
{
    public A() { Container.Register(this); }        
    public void DoIt() { Console.WriteLine("Running!"); }
}
```

Now, let's say that I register my `A` instance by calling a method that only contains an `A` instantiation:

```
public void Init() { var a = new A(); }
```

Theoretically, could compilation be optimized to ignore this assignment, or can I be 100% sure that `A` is *always* instantiated when I call the `Init` method?

**Example** When I run the following code:

```
Init();
...
Container.Run();
```

will `Container._a` always be defined and the output from the `DoIt` method written to the console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler doesn't in general know if the constructor of A has observable side-effects, so it will always call it. It may not keep the variable 'a' around though.

So, the constructor will be called, but the result may not be assigned to the variable; instead the A object may just be immediately registered for garbage collection if nothing else references it. (In your case, something else DOES reference it - namely, the Container class - so it WON'T be garbage-collected!)

In your case, the constructor manifestly DOES have side-effects in any case (so it would be a major error for the compiler to optimise away the constructor call).

In summary:

- The constructor will always be called.
- The assignment of the result to the local variable may not be done because the compiler knows that it has no observable side-effects.
- In your code, something else retains a reference to the constructed object, so it won't be GCed.

Comment: it should not keep the variable 'a', which is not a problem here since  the new object will be referenced by the Container class, so it won't get GC'd until some other 'A' registers with the Container

Comment: Yep good point, I've updated my answer to explicitly mention that!